# How to get ClusterManager items from the Algorithm class

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm working with the `android-maps-utils` lib and trying to inspect the items collection added using the `addItem` ClusterManager, but there is not a method that retrieves this collection. Why does ClusterManager not provide `getItems` method from Algorithm interface?

Is there any way to get those items without creating my own ClusterManager?

The ClusterMarker collection does not represent all items that were added to the ClusterManager, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Utility: how to get all markers from ClusterManager<?>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449438/google-maps-utility-how-to-get-all-markers-from-clustermanager)