# How to get all items from the Google Maps clustermanager in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, markerclusterer

In the Android version of the Google Maps cluster manager it it possible to get the collection of markers from (see [Google Maps Utility: how to get all markers from ClusterManager<?>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449438/google-maps-utility-how-to-get-all-markers-from-clustermanager)). I tried to do the same under iOS, but it doesn't work. The algoritm class doesn't expose the items array.

Is there another way to get the items? Or should I do one of the following:

- Expose the items array by editing the algorithm class.
- Sublass the algorithm class and overwrite the `addItem`, `clearItems` etc methods, so I can maintain a shadow copy of the items array.
- Maintain a shadow copy in another way.

Comment: Still no luck with this?? I want to do the same, I'm not sure if there is a method that could get us back all items. Perhaps we will need to create and modify the original classes and expose the items array from the algorithm classes we use. Or have you found any other solution?

Comment: No. Still using a shadow copy mechanism. It basically works, but has some artefacts, if you have an eye for details.

Comment: Actually we found out that there is a method that brings all items. It is inside the algorithm class: `self.clusterManager.algorithm.allItems()` 
Not sure if this is what you've been looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately if `allItems()` was part of the interface it isn't anymore as of this writing.

Comment: Anyone got any solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

Logically this is the algorithm that brings all the items in the cluster. But I get error when calling items according to zoom value.

```
let clusters = clusterManager.algorithm.clusters(atZoom: 21.0 //self.googleMap.maxZoom)
for c in clusters {

    for i in c.items {

        if let m = i as? POIItem {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```